# Nginx logs write to stdout cause Broken pipe

Tags: nginx, stdout, broken-pipe

I'm using nginx and writing logs to stdout.

We will have about 7000 logs/hour write to stdout and after running the container for some time, we keep getting errors as below:

```
write() to "/dev/stdout" failed (32: Broken pipe) while logging request
```

And below is the access log config:

```
access_log  /dev/stdout  main;
```

Tried to restart the container several times, and will always get this error after the container running for hours or a day.

Below is the nginx image we are using:

```
nginx:1.19.7-alpine-perl
```

Comment: What type of container? Maybe add to your question and check for relevant logging informations for the type of container. There is alot of information available, for different types of containers. I can almost deduct you are talking about docker and in that case, there is alot of relevant information floating around. Welcome and good luck!

Comment: Hi @OldFart,
Thanks, it is nginx container. The version is nginx:1.19.7-alpine-perl

Comment: Check this thread, this is trivial and should be fairly simple... https://serverfault.com/a/634296/414914 - Also, make sure nginx runs with daemon off